# Examples of combinatorial bijections found by considering functors

Tags: co.combinatorics, big-list

Let us assume that I have two sets of combinatorial objects, $A$ and $B$,
and I am looking for a bijection (in particular a map) $\psi:A \to B$ between these sets, usually required to preserve some additional statistic.

For example, a combinatorial proof of the qt-symmetry of the qt-Catalan numbers can be stated in this form, and this is still open.
Same can be said about the [GOG-MAGOG problem](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03305v2.pdf).

Suppose now that $B$ has a lot of structure, perhaps with an action of $S_n$ on it, or similar. 
To find $\psi$, one approach would then be to look for a similar action on $A$, and then require that the maps commute.
This of course adds a lot more restrictions on $\psi$, making the search space smaller.

Usually, articles usually only presents $\psi$, not how it was found.
So my question is, has this line of thinking been used explicitly somewhere?

**Have you used this "functor"-method to find bijections?**

I suppose that inventing a new statistic on $B$, say $\sigma: B \to \mathbb{N}$, and then looking for the corresponding statistic on $\tau:A  \to \mathbb{N}$, such that $ \sigma \circ \phi = \tau$,
also counts as a "functorial" approach, but this is more commonly known as *refinements* or *q*-analogues, and not what I am looking for.

Comment: This question, while interesting, is extremely broad in scope. An enormous family of examples comes just from the topological invariance of Euler characteristic! Are you simply looking for successful examples of categorification, or is there a more specific purpose to your question?

Comment: I remember Viviane Pons telling me once that she found a bijection between two objects (in Catalan combinatorics) by narrowing down the search space by requiring the bijection to respect some statistics (after checking with Sage that said statistics were equidistributed). Sadly, I don't remember the details.

Comment: @ViditNanda: My main interest is showing positivity in different polynomial bases, say Schur positivity.